# Is there a unified formula for the lengths of the median, angle bisector, and altitude of a triangle?

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The (squares of the) lengths of the median, angle bisector, and altitude of an $a$-$b$-$c$ triangle with base $a$ are given by the following:

$$\begin{align}
d_{\text{med}}^2 &= \frac14\left( - a^2 + 2 b^2 + 2 c^2 \right) \tag{1}\\[4pt]
d_{\text{bis}}^2 &= \frac{b c}{(b+c)^2}(a+b+c)(-a+b+c) \tag{2}\\[4pt]
d_{\text{alt}}^2 &= \frac{1}{4a^2}(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \tag{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align}$$

(These can be derived using, for instance, [Stewart's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).)

I'm wondering if there's a unified formula for $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, with the instances distinguished by some auxiliary parameter. In other words,

- Is there a function $f(a,b,c,n)$ such that
  $$f(a,b,c,n_\text{med})=d_\text{med}\qquad
  f(a,b,c,n_\text{bis})=d_\text{bis}\qquad
  f(a,b,c,n_\text{alt})=d_\text{alt}$$
  for some $n_\text{med}$, $n_\text{bis}$, $n_\text{alt}$ that are independent of $a$, $b$, $c$?
- And, is it possible that these particular values of $n$ can be taken as (consecutive) integers?
- And, further, might other special cevians be associated with other specific (possibly integer) values of $n$?

Comment: How are you associating $n=0, 1, 2$ to the altitude, angle bisector, and median? And what are the "interesting results" associated with $n=-\infty, -1, \infty$, and what justifies the association of those value of $n$ to those results? (Hmmm ... After an edit, I read that the associations with $n=-1,0,1,2$ aren't necessarily those you give.)... In any case, as you note, the formula for the length of a cevian is already known; it either *is* or *isn't* an analogue of the "generalized mean" in the way you want. You seem to be asking us to read your mind about how this is supposed to work.

Comment: oh it is not an association, just an example! to explain... it can be the other way round... just an example. perhpas it can be proven by you that -2 gives an altitude. -1 gives a bisector 0 gives us a median. that would be perfect!!!

Comment: BTW: Instead of posting a drafty question and then making a zillion edits, you should use [the sandbox in Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/409) to get your question to a reasonably-stable form. Rampant "live" editing makes it impossible to know when a question is ready for proper consideration.

Comment: the basic idea is that for a natural n you get formula for the altitude. for n+1 a formula for bisector. for n+2 a formula for the median.

Comment: well I guess generalized mean formula was found empirically and it works perfectly. no one knew in advance what exact mean will -2 or +1 give. geometric mean, harmonic, etc.

Comment: The description is quite confusing in this regard. Here's my understanding of what you're asking ... *"Is there a function $f(a,b,c,n)$ that, for a specific $n=n_{\text{alt}}$, yields the length of the altitude of the $a$-$b$-$c$ triangle (with base $a$)? and likewise, for $n=n_{\text{bis}}$ and $n=n_{\text{med}}$, yields the lengths of the angle bisector and median?  And is it possible that these particular values of $n$ can be taken as (consecutive) integers? And, further, might other special cevians be associated with other specific (possibly integer) values of $n$?"*

Comment: I am very glad that you put it this way. 'possibly integer', etc.   Do you suggest to edit/ resubmit the question or to leave it unchanged.?

Comment: I suggest editing. While our comment-discussion may help clarify your intent, people shouldn't have to consult the comments (and very often don't) to understand a question. ... Speaking of which: I'm getting the "avoid extended discussions" warning. I will likely not be responding further. Good luck!

Comment: I went to fix some formatting in the question, but couldn't seem to stop myself from significantly revising the question. :)  Since you used my commented suggestion for your own revision, I didn't think you'd mind. In any case ... Please double-check that I've properly captured your intention.

Comment: If we know a cevian's "Ceva ratio" $r:=|DC|/|BD|$ (where $D$ is the point where the cevian meets side $a$), then Stewart's formula tells us that
$$d^2=\frac{-a^2r+b^2(1+r)+c^2r(1+r)}{(1+r)^2}$$ So, the problem seems to reduce to finding $r$ for each cevian of interest; that is, we want a function $g(a,b,c,n)$ such that $$g(...,n_\text{med})=\frac{a/2}{a/2}=1\qquad g(...,n_\text{bis})=\frac{b}{c}\qquad g(...,n_\text{alt})=\frac{b\cos C}{c\cos B}=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{a^2-b^2+c^2}$$ This seems like an easier problem to wrap one's head around.